# What could cause Electron to not show any errors?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have taken over an Electron project from another developer.

The problem I am facing is that the project does not show any errors. Even including something like `throw "this is an error"` does not produce any output on the main process or render process consoles or any sort of standard error popup.

I have checked to confirm that `electron-unhandled` is not in use and that nothing registers `'uncaughtException'`.

What am I missing that could cause this behavior?

Comment: Does it not produce any output? Check if your predecessors probably disabled console logging, probably like that: `console.log = () => {}` (or the placed a switch to enable/disable console logging)

Comment: Thanks for this! These are exactly the kind of tricks to disable logging that I am trying to find. Yes, no output at all. Unfortunately, that wasn't it. console.log is not redefined anywhere. Neither is console.error. Are there any similar common tricks that are used to suppress output in Electron?

Comment: Can you get a console log if you put one into the code yourself?

Comment: Could you try a search in the project for 'ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE' and 'ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE'? They can prevent output to console: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/environment-variables#electron_no_attach_console-windows

Comment: @seesharper Yes. In that case it shows up fine.

Comment: @Remi Unfortunately neither seem to be in there.

Comment: You're not throwing this in an `async` function called from a `sync` function are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for: unhandledRejection

- **unhandledRejection** : This will catch any thrown errors, or non fatal errors you have successfully handled via throw.
- **uncaughtException** : This only catches fatal errors or errors that would crash your node instance
- **WebWorkers** : There will be yet another console for webworkers if your using those.
- **package.json** : Take a look in here at the script executed to start electron or however your starting it... Make sure the console is not being sent to a remote console.  This feature would allow for debugging the application via Chrome/Firefox vs the standard console. Pretty common for electron apps.  If is done via the startup command.

May look something like this:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function (err) {
   
});
```

Also, make sure you include any modules in your searching for suppressors as the issue may exist somewhere in the node_modules directory and many IDE's (mine does by default) exclude that directory in indexing/searches.

Comment: Eureka! Your last comment about making sure the modules are included was the crux of the matter. A module that the old dev imported was redefining unhandledRejection but the IDE did, as you said, not search within it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another possible reason could be `stdout` and/or `stderr` redirection, the problem is this could be achieved by several ways so it's hard to suggest you **what** to check...

If there is some `child_process` call to launch a sub-process you could check the `stdio` array used, or you can check if some low level operation is performed against file descriptors 1 and 2...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately, there seem to be no references to stdout, stderr or stdio anywhere in the codebase and nothing seems to call child_process.

Answer (score 1):

Are you facing the problem as mentioned in [this official thread](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-disable-alert-dialogs-when-errors-occur/20037). You may disable the original event listeners and manage the ELECTRON_BROWSER_WINDOW_ALERT event by my event listener.

Here is the solution

```
ipcMain.removeAllListeners("ELECTRON_BROWSER_WINDOW_ALERT")
ipcMain.on("ELECTRON_BROWSER_WINDOW_ALERT", (event, message, title)=>{
  console.warn(`[Alert] ** ${title} ** ${message}`)
  event.returnValue = 0 // **IMPORTANT!**
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, idea and sample code. Unfortunately, nothing changed.